# Building LLVM with CMake and Visual Stuidio fails to install,

Tags: c++, cmake, visual-studio-2017, llvm

I am currently facing an issue when building llvm + compiler-rt under windows. I am using the latest vs 2017 community and cmake to generate the solution. Everything goes smoothly.

I then follow the instructions and everything builds. The problem I have is at install time; I get the following error:

```
file INSTALL cannot find
77>  "F:/WORK_IN_PROGRESS/compile/build/$(Configuration)/lib/clang/6.0.0/lib/windows/clang_rt.builtins-x86_64.lib".
```

Everything else installs fine, other libs, headers are all there, and yes I am running visual studio in admin mode just to make sure there are no issue in copying file arounds etc. Here is the full error:

I have double checked and the same path works, the file exists I have tried to go in the correpsonding cmake install and change the slashes to backward-slashes still no luck. I can copy the lib there manually but I am not sure what else I will have to copy and where that s why I am trying to solve it properly. I am off of trunk, but looks like I a problem that has been gone for a while:

```
77>CMake Error at projects/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/cmake_install.cmake:34 (file):
77>  file INSTALL cannot find
77>  "F:/WORK_IN_PROGRESS/compile/build/$(Configuration)/lib/clang/6.0.0/lib/windows/clang_rt.builtins-x86_64.lib".
77>Call Stack (most recent call first):
77>  projects/compiler-rt/lib/cmake_install.cmake:33 (include)
77>  projects/compiler-rt/cmake_install.cmake:33 (include)
77>  projects/cmake_install.cmake:32 (include)
77>  cmake_install.cmake:64 (include)
77>
```

Also, as a side note, it looks like the install process is trying to access a weird old redistributable of vs 2017 and I cannot install it, even after scavenging the installer it fails because there is a new one.
Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been fighting quite a bit with this but for the time being, I have a workaround. The trick was to trigger the INSTALL target from CMake directly without the need to open visual studio, that seems to do the trick.

to build from CMake I simply did:

```
cmake --build . --config Release --target ALL_BUILD
cmake --build . --config Release --target INSTALL
```

All summed up this way is actually quite a bit faster since you avoid all the side work VS does for indexing etc.

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by adding the following line of CMake code:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "\\$\\(Configuration\\)" "$<CONFIG>" output_dir "${output_dir}")
```

here:

```
https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/1692c2fdaacc628cf19638025727496397e52c5a/compiler-rt/cmake/Modules/AddCompilerRT.cmake#L12
```

With this fix, I successfully compiled and installed LLVM 10 with Visual Studio 2017.

I'm new to LLVM. Someone familiar with contributing to LLVM may help me submit this fix to the llvm-project. Thanks!

### UPDATE

This fix is not submitted. The code snippet is given here hoping it will be useful.

```
if(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
  string(REGEX REPLACE "\\$\\(Configuration\\)" "$<CONFIG>" output_dir "${output_dir}")   # <--- The added line
  foreach(build_mode ${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES})
    string(TOUPPER "${build_mode}" CONFIG_SUFFIX)
    set_target_properties("${target}" PROPERTIES
        "ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONFIG_SUFFIX}" ${output_dir}
        "LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONFIG_SUFFIX}" ${output_dir}
        "RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_${CONFIG_SUFFIX}" ${output_dir})
  endforeach()
else()
  set_target_properties("${target}" PROPERTIES
      ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${output_dir}
      LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${output_dir}
      RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${output_dir})
endif()
```

Comment: I can confirm your patch works. Please use [git format-patch -1](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch#_examples) to create a .patch file, then [follow the instructions here](https://llvm.org/docs/Contributing.html#how-to-submit-a-patch) and submit your patch to [LLVM's Phabricator](https://reviews.llvm.org/). Be sure to [tag the appropriate maintainer](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/45344cf7ac5b848f77825ffa37b0cb3b69b9b07b/compiler-rt/CODE_OWNERS.TXT) in Phabricator as well. Your patch would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I will try it at the weekend.

Comment: @AndrewD'Addesio  Was this patch ever included? If so could you share the relevant patch link. I am still seeing this error in 2022 for LLVM 13.

Comment: @Sanket_Diwale This patch is not included. The code snippet is given. You can run a commend to fix AddCompilerRT.cmake before compiling LLVM. You are welcome to submit this patch to the LLVM project.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming to this question now: Marco Giordanos answer almost did it for me, but I had to take some additional steps first (which were not obvious to me):

1. Make sure Visual Studio was in the path, and
2. Add CMake to path

The first was solved by running "Developer Command Prompt for VS2017" instead of regular command prompt, but I am sure there are other ways to accomplish that as well. The second (assuming typical CMake installation path):

```
set PATH=C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;%PATH%
```